# Creating variable of type <derived class> to store <base class> object in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

i have a question about practical use of this example, when you are creating a variable of type derived class to store a variable of base class object.

```
DerivedClass C = new BaseClass();
```

in what case i can use this.

Comment: Do you mean `BaseClass C = new DerivedClass();`? Because your code won't compile.

Comment: No, because i know what BaseClass C = new DerivedClass(); <- this means and how i can use this, i am interested exactly about what i have asked.

Comment: Well... it's meaningless and won't compile ;)

Comment: This is not possible. Think of it in terms of Base class as `Animal` and derived as `Dog`. Doing this your way is akin to saying all `Animal`s are `Dog`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in what case i can use this.

You can't. Ever.

The main point of static typing is so that you can rely on the value of a variable being compatible with the type you've declared. So if you declare a variable as:

```
DerivedClass C;
```

then any value for `C` must be able to be treated as a `DerivedClass`. In particular, all the members of `DerivedClass` must be available. That simply wouldn't be the case if the value is actually a reference to an instance of `BaseClass` which doesn't have all those members.

Fortunately the language rules (and therefore the compiler) understand that this would be a Very Bad Thing and so you'll get a compile-time error.

Comment: Can i do this i such way?

`DerivedClass C = (DerivedClass)new BaseClass();`

Comment: @AlexiAmniashvili: That will compile (I think; certainly if you cast to object first)... then throw a `ClassCastException` at execution time. So it's not *useful*. It's very unclear what you're trying to get out of this question. Do you have something you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: No, i am reading some book about C# and i had such question, if this is possible and if this has some practical use.

Answer (score 0):

If you´re trying to cast an instance of your base-class to an instance of derived-class you have to ensure that the first actually IS a derived-type using `if (obj is DerivedClass) newInstance = (DerivedClass) obj`.

If you need an upcast you have to implement a kind of copying method that copies all members from your base to your derived class using reflection e.g. In this case you have to set some kind of default-value for every member of `DerivedClass` that is NOT part of `BaseClass`. But this is more a hack and might bring some danger because you may create some corrupt instances.